# Assigning a colour to a square side issue

Tags: materials, objects, color, properties

[image][image]I still very new to blender and have a issues with the program on Linux mint. I select a side of a square and assign a colour to it in material properties and some times it will work  and some times it will leave a clear square, like there is nothing there, and some times it will take another sides colour and leave that clear. If i try assigning each side the same colour, I don't seem to have any clear sides. I have a GEforce 210 graphics card if that has known to cause issues. Can any one help please?

Comment: can you show us some screenshots how it looks like? and maybe explain a bit more how you assign the color?

Comment: I just added a example of all the steps I took to get the problem.

Comment: Ok, for me looks like you did everything right. Maybe it is a hardware problem…

Comment: Enable 'Material Preview' (the third icon top right in 3d View): https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/introduction.html#introduction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: @brockmann: maybe i learn something today, but material preview can make faces visible again? Because if i believe his image, he just assigned material to a face (yes, he is in solid view so he won't see his material) so...i don't understand your hint...or maybe i have some lack of knowledge...?

Comment: maybe share your blend file so we can exclude that you have a hardware problem....

Comment: @Chris Yeah, if the viewport is set to material preview and the face is gone it's obviously a bug or the face is just hidden, who knows :) In any case, I just linked one of our famous Q&A's here how to assign it properly to at least get that out of the way...

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering 

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Still have not yet solved the problem . Just added  another picture showing when I try to assign each side one colour and when i assign  a different colour to each side. As you see the one colour assign is a solid colour and not missing any sides. I don't know how to upload a blend file here. I will say though blender  has crashed 3 times, just trying to create a square with different colours.

Comment: Found a solution, I just use bforartists. instead. I don't have this problem with that.